# How to use Request to get form element in nested form vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get form control value (test) in nested page using request.

My HTML file

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHText" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="test" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
Public Sub RegisterNew(id As Guid) Implements testInterface
    test.Value = id.ToString()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsInitProp As Boolean Implements testInterface
    Get
        Return Not Request("test") = String.Empty
    End Get
End Property
```

using `RegisterNew()` I assign value to test field. after assign value when I try to take value in `IsInitProp` property it says `Nothing`.

But if I use normal page (not nested page) as below then this works properly.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="test" runat="server" />
</form>
```

How can I get this hidden field value in nested page?

Comment: You don't, that's not how ASP.NET work. You need to use the object reference. Do a viewsource of the code, you will see that the ID is not test anymore when using an asp control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reference the server control through the page object (`Me`) by ID, like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsInitProp As Boolean Implements testInterface
    Get
        Return Not Me.test.Value = String.Empty
    End Get
End Property
```